# advertising a public wcf service

Tags: wcf, ads

-hi all,

this question maybe downgrade my reputation... but I need some information to how advertise for my free wcf service-

Hope some readers of this question is italian for language reason!

Some one can help me?

-thank you all for your time

Comment: - Someone can tell me how can I have made the question rigth with stackoverflow policy? than you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.webservicelist.com/

Comment: thank you. Some hints to how insert my service?

Comment: Hah, I got downvoted too. I  have no idea, I just remember coming across that site a while back.

Comment: I see.. i'm sorry... but i'll accept your answer to repair the damage